# Android Paging 3: LoadType.APPEND returns null remote keys

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

I've been trying to work out how to fix my issue with `RemoteMediator`'s `APPEND` `LoadType`.

On an empty Room DB, here's how the `LoadType` flows:
REFRESH -> PREPEND -> APPEND (remoteKeys = null, endOfPaginationReached = true)

With at least 10 rows for entity and remote keys table, here's how the `LoadType` flows:
REFRESH -> PREPEND -> APPEND (remoteKeys = prev=null, next=2, endOfPaginationReached = false)

Clearly, my issue is on a fresh installed device (with empty Room DB), the user won't see more than 10 items because `APPEND`'s `state.lastItemOrNull()` is returning `null`.

Here's my code so far:

```
private suspend fun getRemoteKeysForLastItem(state: PagingState<Int, MovieCache>): MovieRemoteKeys? {
    return state.lastItemOrNull()?.let { movie ->
        appDatabase.withTransaction {
            appDatabase.remoteKeysDao().remoteKeysByImdbId(movie.imdbId)
        }
    }
}
```

for my `load()` function:

```
val loadKey = when (loadType) {
            LoadType.REFRESH -> {
                val key = getRemoteKeysClosestToCurrentPosition(state)
                Timber.d("REFRESH key: $key, output: ${key?.nextKey?.minus(1)}")
                key?.nextKey?.minus(1) ?: 1
            }
            LoadType.PREPEND -> {
                Timber.d("PREPEND key requested")
                return MediatorResult.Success(true)
            }
            LoadType.APPEND -> {
                val key = getRemoteKeysForLastItem(state)
                Timber.d("APPEND key: $key")
                appDatabase.withTransaction {
                    val size = movieDao.movies().size
                    val remoteSize = remoteKeysDao.allKeys().size
                    Timber.d("APPEND DB size: $size, remote: $remoteSize")
                }
                key?.nextKey ?: return MediatorResult.Success(true)
            }
        }
```

Here's a sample logcat showing that `APPEND` is `null`
[image]

Leaving my app unable to scroll down even at least once!

Edit: Here is how I save my remote keys:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Finally, this is how I managed to fix this issue, by relying on the remoteKeys on the DB than `PagingState`:

```
LoadType.APPEND -> {
//  val key = getRemoteKeysForLastItem(state) // Doesn't work. state returns NULL even Room has data for both remote keys and entity.
    val key = appDatabase.withTransaction {
        remoteKeysDao.allKeys().lastOrNull() // Workaround
    }
    key?.nextKey ?: return MediatorResult.Success(true)
}
```

Comment: Can you please look into this query? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67951960/paging-3-library-calls-the-load-method-recursively-with-loadtype-append

Comment: Hi Jim, your idea was revolutionary, literally had the same issue although I was using `item keys` instead of `remote keys`. I will post my answer below but couldn't come-up until I saw your approach few days ago. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning `endOfPaginationReached = true` from **LoadType.APPEND** when remote key is `null`, return `endOfPaginationReached = key != null`. Returning `endOfPaginationReached = false` means keep loading which will give you the remote key next time.

```
LoadType.APPEND -> {
    val key = getRemoteKeysForLastItem(state)
    Timber.d("APPEND key: $key")
    appDatabase.withTransaction {
        val size = movieDao.movies().size
        val remoteSize = remoteKeysDao.allKeys().size
        Timber.d("APPEND DB size: $size, remote: $remoteSize")
    }
    key?.nextKey ?: return MediatorResult.Success(key != null)
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. (key != null) fixes the issue for me. 
It is a super weird behavior that after updating the database LoadType.APPEND still returns null.

Answer (score 1):

When working with **RemoteMediator** there are 2 approaches -> [Item Keys](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-network-db#item-keys) or [Remote Keys](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-network-db#page-keys) .

I faced the exact issue very well documented by [@Jim Ovejera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5663340/jim-ovejera) but this time when using `items keys`.

Because APPEND's `state.lastItemOrNull()` is returning `null` (*triggering endOfPageReached = true*) the very first time you populate the database, then you can't rely on the inbuilt `state.lastItemOrNull()`.

The revolutionary idea that Jim came up with is to use the last item on the database instead to calculate the `offset` or the next `item id` to load.

```
    LoadType.APPEND -> {
        val lastItem = state.lastItemOrNull() //returns null 1st time
        val lastDbItemId = dao.selectLast()?.id
        
        if (lastDbItemId== null){ return 
MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)}
                  
           
        lastDbItemId
                            }
```

If your offset is zero-based the above snippet works perfectly but you may need to use `lastDbItemId.plus(1)` if not.

The dao's `selectLast()` function is just a simple SQLite Query returning a **nullable entity**.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name) ")
suspend fun selectLast: Entity?
```

My Entity Table looks like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "table_name")
data class Entity(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
val id: Int? = null .....)
```

I noted setting `autoGenerate=true` creates discrepancies every time new data is loaded.